# Padding on Bootstrap Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do you work with padding on tumbnails using Bootstrap?

I dont want as much padding on the 4 images on the right.

Is there a way to do this using the framwork?

any help would be grand

http://jsfiddle.net/Ys54c/

```
    <div class="row">
        <!-- MAIN LEFT CONTENT! -->
        <div class="col-lg-9">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="alert alert-info">
                      <p><span>Pending approval</span>.Your profile is bring approved. This means others can't search for you just yet.</p>
                    </div>

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-5">
                   <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/800x700" alt="">
                     <div class="caption">
                         <h3>Username</h3>
                         <p>Clapham, London, UK</p>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Wink</a>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Chat</a>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                     <div class="panel panel-default">
                         <div class="panel-heading">
                            New Members
                         </div>
                         <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                         <div class="panel-body">

                         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
                            </a>
                        </div>


                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 ">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                                     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 ">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
                            </a>
                        </div> 







                         </div>
                         <!-- .panel-body -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- /.panel -->
                 </div>
                  </div>





                 </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much a margin issue as it is a layout issue. You are declaring a col-lg-3 class, which divides each column into sections of which each occupies 25% of the space.

I would try placing the images in a single column, and then applying CSS with attributes such as display:inline-block in order for them to line up horizontally. Then you can override the margins and padding with your own stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience using Bootstrap 2 and 3, i haven't seen anything in the framework that let's you change padding for groupings or individual elements. I've always had to isolate these instances and change them as a group or individually.